# /dev/sr0 (live DVD) turns into /dev/sr1 when inserting periphials

Tags: devices, block-device, livecd, squashfs

On a live Linux session, inserting a keyboard or mouse via USB onto the computer causes */dev/sr0* to be *remapped* as */dev/sr1*, which makes the live system unable to access the DVD.

`sudo rename /dev/sr1 /dev/sr0` does rename the *device **file*** but running `lsblk` still shows the DVD drive as sr1.

Additionally, `sudo mount /dev/sr1 /cdrom` -o noatime` (default mounting options) do not fix the Input/Output errors from *loop0*, which represents the SquashFS.

Even after that, I still get an Input/Output errors and SquashFS errors, because SquashFS memorizes unreadable sectors, which causes them **even to be inaccessible, despite the DVD is mounted correctly and available again.**

#### How can I make SquashFS read from the DVD again and reset the errors?

Comment: Which live system (distribution, version)? Is the DVD a USB peripheral? It would help to post the kernel logs (all the kernel logs starting when you insert the USB peripheral that messes up the DVD access). Post logs from a session where you don't try to rename the device file, because that can't help but could add problems of its own.

Comment: @Gilles It is Ubuntu Studio 16.04.2 LTS, and the DVD is internal, but it also happens on a different laptop where the DVD drive is an external one with USB. I will post the kernel logs the next time it happens.